# How to check nvarchar value from nvarchar SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my temporary table :

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpRecentTxns(SerialID nvarchar(50) null,TranDate datetime2 null)

select * 
from #tmpRecentTxns 
where #tmpRecentTxns.SerialID NOT IN 
         (SELECT distinct Phone 
          FROM ApplicationVariables 
          WHERE datediff(n, vardatetime, getdate()) <= 300)
```

Here `Phone` datatype is `nvarchar(10)` in database.

Problem : when I am going to select value it is taking too much time.

Please help me out how to remove this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this query?  I infer find all transactions where there isn't a recent phone number in "ApplicationVariables".  Can you explain your logic more?

Comment: Did you create appropriate indexes on your temp table? Why do you create a temp table, do you really need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the fact your `Phone` is of type `NVARCHAR(10)` is the reason for poor performance.

First of all, you should make sure you have an index on the `vardatetime` column in your `ApplicationVariables` table (including the `Phone` column).

```
CREATE INDEX IX_AppVar_VarDateTime
ON dbo.ApplicationVariables(vardatetime) INCLUDE(Phone)
```

Second, you should change the query so that this index can be used:

```
SELECT distinct Phone 
      FROM ApplicationVariables 
      WHERE vardatetime >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -300, GETDATE())
```

Also: I would recommend to use the `MINUTE` specifier for `DATEDADD` or `DATEDIFF` - much clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will give the same output as you have.

```
select * 
from #tmpRecentTxns 
where #tmpRecentTxns.SerialID 
  not in (select Phone 
          from ApplicationVariables 
          where vardatetime >= dateadd(minute, -300, getdate()))
```

It will allow you to use an index on `vardatetime`.

Comment: Thanks a lot to help me out from this problem, since morning i was trying for this. :), Its working fine.